# How to change the color and style of text in a JList?

Tags: java, swing, colors, jlist, defaultlistmodel

I have a DefaultListModel that contains a list of names. When the names are added to the list, they are just added as Strings. What I need to do is change the color / style (ie, italicize) of some of the names at certain times. Is there any efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a custom renderer. See [Writing a Custom Renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer).